# Fade in <li> items one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have horizontal menu. It looks like that

```
<ul>
<li>Sample 1</li>
<li>Sample 2</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to fadein them one by one on page load?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function fadeIn(i, elements, duration, callback){
    if(i >= elements.length)
        $.isFunction(callback) && callback();
    else
        elements.eq(i).fadeIn(duration, function(){
           fadeIn(i+1, elements, duration, callback);
        });        
}

fadeIn(0, $('ul li'), 100, function(){console.log("animation finished!");});
```

working demo :

### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/7KQbB/

And of course you can pluginify the code for a more jquery-like synthax:

```
$.fn.fadeInEach = function(duration,callback){
    function fadeIn(i,elements,duration,callback){
        if(i >= elements.length)
            typeof callback == 'function' && callback();
        else
            elements.eq(i).fadeIn(duration, function(){
               fadeIn(i+1, elements, duration, callback);
            });        
    }
    fadeIn(0, this, duration, callback);
    return this;
}
```

Now you can use this plugin exactly as the native `fadeIn` method :

```
$('li').fadeInEach(100,function(){alert('animation has finished');});
// if you want to animate all of the elements in the same time use fadeIn : 
// $('li').fadeIn(100,function(){alert('animation has finished');});
```

The great thing about this approach is that it works on any elements (not only li's).
Here's the demo for this little plugin :

### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/7KQbB/1/

Answer (score 4):

```
$("li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(500*i).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This way they will all fade in at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
jQuery(document).ready() {
    $('ul li').hide(); 

    $('ul li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(50*index).fadeIn(200);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, you could handle the animation/fadein part with css animations:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Vt86Y/2/)**

### Markup

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
li
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: pink;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.myList li {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    animation: fadeIn 600ms ease both;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.myList.play li {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

### JQuery

```
$(".myList li").each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr("style", "-webkit-animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;"
                 + "-moz-animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;"
                 + "-o-animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;"
                 + "animation-delay:" + i * 200 + "ms;");
    if (i == $(".myList li").size() -1) {
        $(".myList").addClass("play")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that they show up one immediately after the other, you can use a callback function in the fadeIn effect:

For example:

```
var count = $('li').length;
var start = 0;
function sequence(){
$('li').eq(start).fadeIn(1000,function(){
    start++;
    if(start<count) sequence();
});
}
sequence();
```

See it [work](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/4r89T/).